# wordpress + cyrillic characters with SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: mssql

I have a blog running on a windows 2008 machine with SQL server 2008 r2. WP version 3.3.2

I have an English blog, but I would like to post some content in Russian.
When I try and post the content I get question marks where the Cyrillic characters should be. I see the same question marks stored in the DB.
I tried inserting the post manually in to the database and it works, i.e. the issue is not the sql server itself, since it can store Cyrillic characters.
I already tried disabling all plug-ins, and that did not help.

Is this a known issue? Is there any work around?